# Virtual Hosts apache ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: apache, xampp

Alguien podría ayudarme? Configuré un virtualhost en Apache para que al ingresar a la dirección [testsistema](http://www.testsistema.com) me lleve a la pagina de inicio de mi sistema diseñado en laravel, pero al ingresar a esta dirección el navegador me da el mensaje de que no se puede acceder al sitio web. La pagina `www.testsistema.com` ha rechazado la conexión. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, pero al ingresar a **`www.testsistema.com:8000`** me muestra la pagina principal de xampp. Mi archivo httpd-vhost esta configurado de la siguiente manera

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
  ServerName localhost:8000
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8000>
  DocumentRoot "C:/web/Sistema/public"
  ServerName www.testsistema.com
  <Directory "C:/web/Sistema/public"
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Mi archivo httpd está de la siguiente manera:

```
#
# MaxRanges: Maximum number of Ranges in a request before
# returning the entire resource, or one of the special
# values 'default', 'none' or 'unlimited'.
# Default setting is to accept 200 Ranges.
#MaxRanges unlimited

#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
# Defaults: EnableMMAP On, EnableSendfile Off
#
#EnableMMAP off
#EnableSendfile off

# Supplemental configuration
#
# The configuration files in the conf/extra/ directory can be 
# included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of 
# the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as 
# necessary.

# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

# Multi-language error messages
Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

# Fancy directory listings
Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

# Language settings
Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf

# User home directories
Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

# Real-time info on requests and configuration
Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf

# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
#Include conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf

# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
#Attention! WEB_DAV is a security risk without a new userspecific configuration for a secure authentifcation 
#Include conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf

# Various default settings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf
# Implements a proxy/gateway for Apache.
Include "conf/extra/httpd-proxy.conf"
# Various default settings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-default.conf"
# XAMPP settings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"

# Configure mod_proxy_html to understand HTML4/XHTML1
<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

# XAMPP: We disable operating system specific optimizations for a listening
# socket by the http protocol here. IE 64 bit make problems without this.

AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
# AJP13 Proxy
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
<IfModule mod_proxy_ajp.c>
Include "conf/extra/httpd-ajp.conf"
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

y mi archivo de windows hosts de la siguiente manera:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost

127.0.0.1 www.testsistema.com
```

Alguien sabe si hay algo que me falte configurar o algo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: tu problema es que no levantastes el port 8000 en apache debes levantarlo

Answer (score 1):

Esta linea deberia estar comentada en el archivo de hosts:

```
For Windows Vista or for Windows Server 2008
```

En el archivo del virtual host deberías quitar el primer virtual server que escucha en el puerto 8000 dado que apache encuentra ese primero y deriva los requests a ese virtual host, por eso ves la página de xamp:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
  ServerName localhost:8000
</VirtualHost>
```

Por otro lado no me quedó claro en tu pregunta pero si no querés poner el `:8000` en la url, tenes que usar el puerto HTTP por default que es el 80. Es decir que en el virtual host en lugar de 8000 tiene que decir 80.

Para poder usar ese puerto no tiene que haber otro servidor ya escuchando ahi.

Answer (score 0):

Para **GNU/Linux**

Debes abrir el puerto de Apache2, se ubica en la ruta:

```
/etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

Debes agregar el puerto en la configuracion en ese archivo , seria algo como :

```
Listen 8000
```

Reinicia apache2:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

**Para Windows** varia mucho donde puede estar el archivo ports.conf incluso no puede estar, si no esta en el httpd agrega la linea:

```
Listen 8000
```

Ideal antes de que llames a los virtualhost, luego de esto reinicia apache2